# How to append a variable to a named credential?

Tags: apex, httprequest

Here is my small code that calls a named credential. Now how do I call the endpoint utilizing the named credential and adding a path to it like below? Currently I get a 404 error

```
string filename = 'filename;
string s3Bucket = 's3-bucket';
string path = s3Bucket +'/'+filename;

request.setEndpoint('callout:AWSApiGateway/+path');
```

Here is my Named Credential -
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the quote in the wrong place:

```
request.setEndpoint('callout:AWSApiGateway/'+path);
```